# In PHP using slim I can not route to URL /loveshared

Tags: php, routes, slim

A very weird question.

I can not setup a route in slim to use the URL /loveshared

```
$app->get('/loveshared', function() use ($app) {
  echo "hello";
});
```

If I navigate in my browser to localhost/loveshared, I get a 404.  I also get this 404 message when I push to my server.

I did a Find in Files... in the top direction of my project for the string loveshared.  The only place it found the string was in my router file.

I also went through and did:
/l, /lo, /lov, /love, /loves.../loveshared All the routes work, up until loveshared.  I also did /sharedlove and /stuffshared and they both worked.

Can anyone else confirm that /loveshared does not work with slim as a route?

Comment: Are you able to get similarly configured content to render? Something other than what's here?

Comment: Yes, if I type $app->get('/anythingelse', function() use ($app) { it will render the page loveshared.jade.  I can also  render any other page with my render call.

Comment: Just a note, you can post your question to the Slim Git issue system and Josh Lockhart will probably give you an answer. I, uh, doubt that's what's going on, though. You could do a grep or search within your source for that phrase, too.

Comment: I searched the source in my entire project tree for the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded a fresh copy of [Slim 2.2.0](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/zipball/master), placed it as-is on my personal site (`PHP 5.3.13`) running on `Linux duhr 2.6.32.8` in shared host environment (Dreamhost). Then I created a file, `t.php`, and pasted the following into it:

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/loveshared', function () use ($app) {
    echo "<p>This is a test of the loveshared controller label in the URL of a Slim project.</p>";
});

$app->run();
```

http://jfcoder.com/slim/t.php/loveshared

And it runs as expected. There's either some kind of environment cause (rogue or misconfigured `.htaccess` file?), or something. You would need to recreate it in some way to be able to triangulate and find the problem.

Have you tried what I have done and see if it still causes the problem you're describing?

Comment: Ok, I did what you said.  And there was no issue.  So I was looking at the actual directory structure of my project, and I had an actual folder called loveshared.  This is what caused the issue.  So even if you have your .htaccess route through your index, your directories are still public... interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I've done this before: Encountered a bizarro problem, looked fruitlessly around for a cause, and "settled" on a possible cause that was outlandish but seemingly the only option. You get boxed in and just need someone to job your thinking.

Comment: hah.. true, thank you. I thought slim had something against love shared.

Answer (score -1):

Works fine for me

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/loveshared', function() use ($app) {
  echo "hello";
});

$app->run();
```